# Big O Notation of a Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, big-o

My textbook is saying that the Big O Notation for finding a Node in a Binary Tree is O(log<sub>2</sub>N), if `N = 1` then log<sub>2</sub>N would be 0, which is impossible? Would this just be rounded up to `1` or is there more to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Big-O notation is meant to describe how an algorithm's execution time (or memory consumption, or...) scales when the amount of data (or whatever `N` describes) increases towards infinity. It's not meant to provide a precise runtime when given specific values of `N`. With low values of `N`, constant factors tend to dominate anyway. In this case, all you're meant to derive is that this specific algorithm's execution time scales logarithmically.

Answer (score 4):

The O-notation only cares about the limiting behavior as N goes to ∞. Formally, a nonnegative function f is in class O(g(n)) if there is a constant C and another constant N such that

```
n ≥ N ⇒ f(n) ≤ C g(n).
```

Constant factors and small values of n do not matter at all.

Comment: I should inquire about adding TeX support to this board's Markdown engine.

Comment: I wish. Alas, [someone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60020) ruled it out. Not cool. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Big O is the asymptotic complexity - the actual runtime is something like log<sub>2</sub>N + C, so for `N = 1` you'd have a runtime of `C`

Comment: So it's similar to derivatives where you just tack on a `+ C`?

Comment: @user1327636: No, it's nothing like that at all.

Comment: @user1327636 No, the asymptotic complexity just takes the largest term, so for example if your algorithm's runtime is 4n^2 + 5n + 8 or whatever then its Big O is O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

First off, the statement that the big `O` of finding a node in a binary tree of `N` nodes is `O(log N)` is false. That statement is true for a *binary search tree* but not for a general binary tree.

> if N = 1 then log N would be 0, which is impossible? Would this just be rounded up to 1 or is there more to this?

Doesn't matter. To say that `f` is big `O(log n)` is to say that there is a constants `C` and `N` so that

```
n >= N implies f(n) <= C * g(n)
```

That is, *eventually* `f` is bounded by `C * g`. So, it just doesn't matter if it's impossible to satisfy for a finite number of values including `n = 0`. That is `O` is about describing *asymptotic* behavior, not all behavior.

Comment: Is it true only for BST or Balanced BST?

Comment: It depends whether we are talking about average-case performance or worst-case performance. Worst case is linear, average case is `O(log n)` since the "average" binary search tree has height `O(log n)`.

Comment: I have the impression that when we talk about Big O, that is for worse case only. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: No. That's not the case. For example, you'll commonly see people say that quicksort is `O(n log n)`. But of course, that's only on average as in the worst case with bad pivot choices quicksort degenerates to quadratic performance.

Comment: That is correct, I have also seen it many places, people mention it like that. But don't you think that is just wrong practice. I read that for lower bound and average case, Omeaga and Theta notations are used respectively.(or may be otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It will be zero only, but you have to first decide in which context you want to discuss it. If you look at the definition of BigO then there is no need to substitute value of N, just try to understand what will be worse case.

But if you are thinking in terms of time, there is nothing to search when there only one node in tree.

Last but not the least, this log(n) time complexity is for balanced Binary search tree not for  normal Binary Tree.